# Use of `even` to emphasize the desired outcome of a request

Tags: word-usage

Is the word `even` correctly used to emphasize that arranging a call is the preferable outcome?

> I'd greatly appreciate if you could `even` find some time to discuss this on a call with me. In this case, please use the link below to choose the most convenient time slot for the call:

Context: outreach email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There, **even** alludes to something outside the context you've given us, and means something like "go further than *that*" or "do more than *that*", where *that* refers to the thing alluded to, the thing a call would be preferable to.

> I'd appreciate it if you could email me the information, and I would be very grateful if you could even find some time to discuss this on a call.

You are not using "in this case" idiomatically.  *In this case* refers to a specific objective condition not to a person's *potential* willingness to speak with you on the phone.

> Normally we would advise someone in your financial position to invest in widgets, but in this case we are advising against that and would suggest that put your money in gizmos.

**this** implies closeness, something you can literally or figuratively point to as if it were present, and so it doesn't work with mere possibility, with **if**.  This would be better:

> In *that* case, please use the link below.

The demonstrative **that** points to something that is literally distant or figuratively "remote", and thus it goes much better with "*even* ... do X", since that construction with **even** establishes "X" as something less likely or in some way more difficult or a greater imposition than something else.

However, **case** is still a problem, since willingness to find time to speak with you is not really a "case" or "specific condition" either. These would be idiomatic:

> If *that* is possible, please use the link below...
>
> If you are able to phone, please use the link below...

There are many other ways of phrasing it as well.